# Standards in char array declaration in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

What is the best practice on declaring strings / char arrays in C?
I have the below samples and comments.

Code#1
How to properly declare the below?

```
char message1[] = "abc";  // will add \0 (null character in the end. so message1 is not equal to message2)  
char message2[] = {'a','b','c'}; // tedious to type if you have hundreds of characters to add
```

Does the `recv()` socket function in C adds null terminating character at the end?

Code#2
How to compare *message4* to *message3* if matched partially?

```
char message3[] = {'a','b','c','e','f'}  
char message4[] = {'a','b'}
```

Just exploring and new to programming .

Regards

sya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `char message1[] = "abc";` is proper and the normal way. The `""` means that a null terminator is added at the end automatically.
- `char message2[] = {'a','b','c'};` is wrong, this is not a C string since it is not null terminated. You could have included a `'\0'` at the end and then it would become be a correctly declared C string.
- `revc` has nothing to do with strings at all, it works on raw data and knows nothing about strings. It deals with given sizes in bytes.
- Normally you compare strings with `strcmp`, but in the `message3`+`message4` case, you don't have strings since they were not null terminated. You could instead compare them as raw data with

  `memcmp(message3, message4, sizeof(message4))` where it is known that `message4` is the smallest one.

Answer (score 2):

**Initialising char arrays**

If you are intending to create a NUL-terminated string, you should ***always*** use double-quotes to initialise it, as in your `message1[]`. This automatically (and implicitly) adds the  NUL as the last character in the array.

It is quite rare to initialise a `char` array to anything other than a NUL-terminated string. If you were using it to store non-string data, you would probably declare it as a `int8_t` or `uint8_t` array instead.

However, there are exceptions. If, for example, you were creating a lookup table, indexed by an unsigned integer, to convert a value in the range of 0...15 to its ASCII equivalent in hex, you might use the format of `message2[]` to make it evident you're never going to use the array as a NUL-terminated string.

That said, most developers would still, for brevity, use a quoted string instead (`"0123456789abcdef"`), accepting a one-byte waste of space.

**`recv()` semantics**

The `recv()` function acts just like `read()`, so the same principles apply. It puts exactly and only the number of characters it returns as its return value into the supplied buffer. It does not add a terminal NUL.

**Comparing fixed-size arrays**

You can't use `strlen()` to determine the length of `message3[]` or `message4[]`, as they've been defined with curly brackets, and will not be NUL-terminated. You must assume you *will* overrun the end of the array!

However, the fact that both their lengths are predefined (`char x[] = /*...*/;` rather than `char *y = /*...*/;`) works in your favour. You can use `sizeof()` on each, take the `min()` of the two values, and compare only up to that minimum length, thus preventing array overrun.

You should put some thought into whether you consider `message3[]` "greater than" `message4[]`, given it has the same initial substring but greater length, or whether you consider them equal for your application's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are just characters arrays, they are usually ended by a null terminator allowing functions like `strlen, strcmp, strcpy, etc...` to work on them.

`recv()` does not end the buffer with a null terminator, instead it returns the length of the message that was recieved, so if you where to manipulate this buffer as a string, you should use limited functions such as `strncmp, strncpy, etc...` in which you can explicitly give the size of the array.

`char message1[] = "abc";` or `const char* message1 = "abc";` are the usual ways of defining a string literals.

So to compare message3 and message4 up the the n-th character you may use `strncmp`